# How to access a flash object embedded via swfobject's embedSWF?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flash, swfobject

I have to call an ActionScript method via Javascript, but I have a problem accessing the flash object itself. I embed the flash file via the help of [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).

Previously, when I use the static publishing approach, I could easily get the flash object by calling these methods:

```
swfobject.registerObject("flash_object", "9", "expressInstall.swf");
var flash_object = swfobject.getObjectById("flash_object");
```

For some technical reasons, now I have to use the dynamic publishing approach (using *swfobject.embedSWF*). But, as mentioned in the documentation, the method *getObjectById* can only be used if you use static publishing approach.

Now, how can I access the flash object?

Cheers,
Andree

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the good old `document.getElementById("flash_object")`

Just be sure to do it after page load.  You can set it up via the [callback function](http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/the-callback-function/), too:

```
var mySWF = null;
var flashvars = {};
var params = {};
var attributes = {};
var embedHandler = function (e){
  mySWF = e.ref; //e.ref is a pointer to the <object>
  //do something with mySWF
};

swfobject.embedSWF("/path/to/file.swf", "flash_object", "550", "400", "9", "/path/to/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes, embedHandler);
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work in Firefox... It returns null! :( does anyone know why, or how to get round it? Thanks!

Comment: i just updated my answer to use swfobject's callback API: e.ref will return a pointer to the <object>, no need for document.getElementById

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going through the documentation on [How to Integrate Flex with Java EE applications.](http://www.artima.com/articles/enterprise_flex_part_1.html)

It explains how to use Flashvars to pass data from javascript to actionscript method. I used it myself and it works just fine.